# Can I make an AMI from a running instance that uses instance-store as its root device?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami, ec2-ami

Or is it absolutely necessary to have an EBS backed storage? Does anyone have manuals/Howtos?

I am following the manual given on this [site](http://gista.blog.root.cz/2010/10/18/creating-debian-amazon-ec2-ebs-ami-using-debootstrap/).

Comment: Amazon documentation for this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-snapshot-s3-linux.html

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can create an AMI from either an EBS or S3-backed running instance. The simplest way is to use the [AWS Management Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com)  to select the instance and click 'Create Image' from the Instance Actions menu.

This will create either an EBS or S3-backed AMI, depending on the type of instance.

Be aware that creating an AMI from a `Running` instance is inherently potentially unsafe - the storage is not imaged as a hard 'point-in-time' snapshot, so changes to the filesystem whilst the image is being created may not be recorded, and may even result in a compromised image. You should quiesce the OS as far as possible before starting.

Note also that your instance will reboot during the image-creation process, so make sure you're prepared for any temporary loss of service from the VM.

Comment: The options are grayed-out. And I cant stop the large instance, only reboot it. What now?

Comment: PS: its a root storage device, not a EBS backed one.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if this is something to do with options configured for the baseline image...? Alas, I'm a Windows EC2 user, and can't offer any further suggestions for Linux VMs.

Answer (score 6):

If you bundle a Windows EBS instance while it is running, its Administrator password will be reset by Amazon's rebundling tools - so you'll have to use the EC2 "get Admin password" function with instances launched from the new AMI.

If you stop your Windows instance before rebundling, its Administrator password will remain intact through the rebundling process.

I don't know if this is documented anywhere, but it's certainly been my experience with Windows 2003 instances.

Answer (score 2):

you will to refer the manual for the three commands:

```
ec2-bundle-vol, ec2-upload-bundle, ec2-register.
```

Keep at hand your private and certificate key (eg. pk.pem, cert.pem files) and your access and shared key. Download the ec2 ami tools and setup the environment variables for the ec2 ami tools. This site might give you the details on how to bundle the volume, create the images, upload them to S3 and finally register it as your own ami.

http://alestic.com/2009/06/ec2-ami-bundle

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create an AMI from an EBS running instance using the AWS management console. as mentioned by [Eight-Bit Guru](https://stackoverflow.com/users/233653/eight-bit-guru) by clicking 'Create Image' from the Instance Actions menu.

For the S3 backed instance it is currently not possible without bundling the instance.
If you are using a linux ami then you have two ways as explained in this guide:

- [Creating an AMI from S3 backed instance - For Linux](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/creating-an-ami-s3-linux.html)

For windows based S3 backed instance you can follow other guide

- [Creating an AMI from S3 backed instance - For Windows](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/Creating_InstanceStoreBacked_WinAMI.html)

Hope this will help for creating an AMI for S3 backed intances.

Answer (score -1):

An exam guide says "Yes only if 'no reboot' is checked"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).